# Dispatcher only updates UI the first time it's called

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dispatcher

I have a class that does a potentially long-running operation, so it reports its progress by firing an event, and I plan to run it in a separate thread from the UI.  To test the status message event will update a databound listbox as planned, I made a dummy class with the same type of event:

```
class NoisyComponent
{
    public EventHandler<string> OnProgress;
    protected void prog(params string[] msg)
    {
        if (OnProgress != null)
            OnProgress(this, string.Join(" ", msg));
    }

    public void Start(int lim)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        {
            prog("blah blah blah", i.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

The page I'm testing it with has a listbox:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=appstate.progress_messages, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"></ListBox>
```

And I'm starting the task in OnRender:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var noisy = new NoisyComponent();
        noisy.OnProgress += (sender, msg) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                (App.Current as App).appstate.progress_messages.Add(msg);
                UpdateLayout();
            });
        };
        Task.Run(() => { noisy.Start(5); });
    }
```

`appstate.progress_messages` is a dependency property

```
    public List<string> progress_messages
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(progress_messagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(progress_messagesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty progress_messagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("progress_messages", typeof(List<string>), typeof(AppState), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));
```

I expected to see a new "blah blah blah #" line in the listbox every 200ms, but instead I just see the first one ("blah blah blah 0") and nothing else.  I've set a break point inside the `Dispatcher.Invoke` lambda, and it is definitely getting run multiple times, and the property is being updated, but it's just not being shown in the UI.

I thought the problem might be that since the property is a list, it's only being assigned to once, and then the `Add` method is being called on the existing object, and the changes are not being "detected" by the dependency property.  But so far I've found no mention of special steps that are necessary if a dependency property is a collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but...

try making progress_messages an ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<string> progress_messages
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(progress_messagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(progress_messagesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty progress_messagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("progress_messages", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(AppState), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));
```

Comment: Wow, great catch!  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really the best way to do it in terms of compatibility. A better solution would probably be to make it of type ICollection<string> and handle the CollectionChanged event of the collection to raise the property changed event. BUT, for your needs this will suffice.